# Why isn't a pendulum clock considered a perpetual machine?

Tags: friction, harmonic-oscillator, perpetual-motion

Why do people say that a [perpetual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion) is one that runs for eternity? Wouldn't a machine that runs taking no energy from outside but sometimes needs to be restarted, such as pendulum clock, be considered a perpetual machine? It just needs to be restarted one or two times a month. Given that physicists love approximations, wouldn't restarting a machine two times a month be higher order smaller term that we could throw away and call the pendulum clock a perpetual machine?

Comment: With this logic the planets are a perpetual motion machine as far as our lifetimes are concerned.

Comment: The pendulum clock takes energy from outside: either from a spring or from a mass that slowly descends. Restarting the machine means push some energy from outside into it, it is the same as changing the battery of a quartz clock.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing as a physical quantity that is small or large in an absolute sense. Quantities can only be small or large compared to other quantities. Furthermore, comparisons *must* be between quantities with the same physical dimensions (which can be unitless).

For example, sometimes a velocity is much less than the speed of light: $v \ll c$, or equivalently $v/c \ll 1$. Sometimes we say "$v$ is small" but the understanding is that we *mean* to say "$v$ is small compared to $c$."

In your case, you want to throw out a quantity. Either it's the time between rewindings $T \approx 1\ \mathrm{month}$ (which you say is long) or the frequency of rewindings $f \approx 4\times10^{-7}\ \mathrm{Hz}$ (which you say is small). But you haven't specified what the quantity is large or small compared to.

Finally, whenever a quantity is properly neglected, it can be viewed in the paradigm $x + \epsilon \approx x$, where $\lvert \epsilon \rvert \ll \lvert x \rvert$. You can replace one number by another if they differ by small amount (compared to the actual value). But you can never just replace a number by $0$ in vacuo. For example, if your formula is $P = 3\pi (\epsilon/x)^2$, then even if $\lvert \epsilon \rvert \ll \lvert x \rvert$, $P \approx 0$ can be a *very* bad approximation. If the scale of the problem is set by $Q = 16 (\epsilon/x)^4$, then $P$ is in fact a large quantity, and you wouldn't be justified in saying $Q + P \approx Q + 0 = Q$.

---

As for perpetual motion itself, we define it to mean you don't inject energy **ever**. One month is *short* compared to "infinite time," and in fact any finite length of time is "infinitely short" compared to $\infty$. As far as infinity is concerned, restarting your clock once a month is no different from restarting it once every nanosecond.

Comment: +1 but you kinda took the long route there; I'd probably swap the two sections.

Answer (score 2):

It is not considered a perpetual motion machine for two reasons:

1. a month is not perpetuity
2. the pendulum clock does take energy from outside- when you say 'restarted' what you mean is resupplied with energy from outside.

As for your opening line and your final suggestion, the entire point of the concept of a perpetual motion machine is to show that nothing can run forever without being resupplied with energy- to illustrate a principle. Making approximations that blur the principle you are trying to highlight would be rather pointless.

Answer (score 0):

I have an old pendulum clock that needs winding every week.  Winding involves raising a block of iron weighing a few kilograms through a distance of about a metre.  In no way is this a perpetual motion machine.